# Let OCaml function work with lists and ints

Tags: ocaml

How can I make this function can fit with List and Int?

```
type 'a tree = 
  | Leaf
  | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree;;

let rec fold_inorder f acc t =
  match t with
  | Leaf           -> acc
  | Node (l, x, r) -> 
      let ar = fold_inorder f acc r in
      let an = x :: ar in
      fold_inorder f an l;;
```

I am trying to

```
fold_inorder (fun acc x -> acc + x) 0 (Node (Node (Leaf,1,Leaf), 2, Node (Leaf,3,Leaf)));;
```

But give me error:

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         'a list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've restricted your accumulator type to being a list. In your recursion, you write

```
let an = x :: ar in
fold_inorder f an l;;
```

`an` is clearly a list (it was constructed using the `::` list constructor), and it's being passed as the second argument to `fold_inorder`. Hence, `fold_inorder` can only accept lists as the second argument. On the other hand, when you call `fold_inorder` at the bottom, you pass `0` as the second argument, which is an integer and not a list, hence the error.

Rather than using `::` to build `an` (the middle accumulator), you should use your supplied `f` function, which was given in order to combine values.

```
let an = f ar x in
```

Comment: It should always raise questions when a function takes an argument but never uses it. If an argument that's supposed to be a function simply has an inferred type `'a` (or `'b` or similar), something is off.